# Creating Image Slider with Zoom Functionality in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a project with an image slider with zoom functionality which is deployment target is iOS 5.1 and it works fine. But when I upgraded to iOS 6, image sliding is working but can't zooming. So, when I pinch to zoom, the image goes out of screen. How can I create an image(s) slider in iOS 6?

Comment: I solved the problem. So, all of UIImageView(s) are subviews of a UIView that named as "zoomableView" additionally the UIView is subview of UIScrollView. I forgot implement the UIScrollView delegate method to zooming that is followig code:

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return zoomableView;
}

Comment: what are u using in sliderValueChanges Method